# php get search result number of database table

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

i would like to be be able to get the number of search results in a particular table of my database (let's name it wp_postmeta). For example, if i search for the exact phrase "Wednesday(3 Sep)", i want to be able to get the number of search results via php.

database example

```
meta_id|post_id|meta_key           |meta_value

1      |123    |delivery-schedule  |Wednesday (3 Sep)
2      |124    |delivery-schedule  |Wednesday (3 Sep)
3      |125    |delivery-schedule  |Thursday (4 Sep)
4      |126    |delivery-schedule  |Friday (5 Sep)
5      |127    |delivery-schedule  |Wednesday (3 Sep)
```

So in this case, i should get the result as `3`. sorry if this sounds too easy. but i cant find my answer anywhere. thanks!

<--this is what i have tried based on gihanmu suggestion-->

```
function test1() {
    $variable = "Wednesday(3 Sep)";
     $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value='".$variable."'";
    //In your example $variable is Wednesday(3 Sep)
     $result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
     $count_array=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     $exact_count=array_shift($count);
     echo $exact_count;
 }
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'test1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value='".$variable."'";
//In your example $variable is Wednesday(3 Sep)
 $result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
 $count_array=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 $exact_count=array_shift($count);
```

$count_array is an array, so you have to pull the first element out using array_shift() function to get the $exact_count

Comment: Thank you. However, when i input into my function.php. it results in the following error `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in...` is it a problem on my end?

Comment: Is it possible you could post your function.php somewhere so we can se it ?

Comment: Hi Gihanmu, refer to my editted question above. Thanks!

Comment: so what is your problem now? still the same issue?

Comment: Thanks manage to solve it now. realize that i did not create a connection

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(meta_id) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = 'Wednesday (3 Sep)';
```

But since you're using PHP, you're going to need mysqli; maybe something like this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$mydate = 'Wednesday (3 Sep)';  
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(meta_id) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = ?");  
$stmt->bind_param('s', $mydate);  
$result = $stmt->execute();  
$stmt->bind_result($col1);  
while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
  echo "you have {$col1} rows matching $mydate\n";  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, somehow your code result in the following error. is it a problem on my end? `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object `

Comment: sorry, i thought you may already be using mysqli, but you need to first create your mysqli connection as per the manual; http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php  i edited the answer to include creating the connection.

Comment: no worries. Its just that i am unfamiliar with sql and hence the trouble. But anyway after trying your updated code. i got the following error. `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object`. is it a problem with connection to mysqli again?

Comment: yes - it seems your mysqli object is not created, because you couldn't connect.  Did you swap in your actual mysql hostname, user, pass, db, etc?  Take some time and have a look at this here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: manage to get it working in the end. However, it only show up 1 no matter what value i set in `$mydate`. Thanks anyway.